# Return maximum of first value entry looping over keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I would like to get the maximum of the first value 10,40 -> 40.
I can use this below, but is there a python way in one line instead of the for loop

```
    soilLayer[0] = [ 10,    50,    0.3,   1600, 1800,    5,  30 ]
    soilLayer[1] = [ 40,    50,    0.3,   1600, 1800,    5,  30 ]
    heigth = []
    position = 0
    for name in sorted( soilLayer.keys() ):
        heigth.append( soilLayer[name][position] )
    print( max( heigth ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few solutions in native Python:

```
soilLayer = {0: [ 10,    50,    0.3,   1600, 1800,    5,  30 ],
             1: [ 40,    50,    0.3,   1600, 1800,    5,  30 ]}


# turn each list into an iterator, apply next to each, then find maximum
res = max(map(next, map(iter, soilLayer.values())))  # 40

# create a list of first values, then calculate maximum    
res = max(list(zip(*soilLayer.values()))[0])  # 40

# use generator comprehension, most Pythonic
res = max(x[0] for x in soilLayer.values())  # 40

# functional equivalent of generator comprehension
from operator import itemgetter
res = max(map(itemgetter(0), soilLayer.values()))  # 40
```

---

Another way, if you are happy using a 3rd party library, is to use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.array(list(soilLayer.values()))[:, 0].max()  # 40.0
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you don't need to sort when you want to find the maximum. You can use `operator.itemgetter` to get multiple items at once and zip to get the first items. Then, you can all the `max` on result.

```
from operator import itemgetter

max(next(zip(*itemgetter(*soilLayer.keys())(soilLayer)))
```

Comment: `max(next(zip(*itemgetter(*soilLayer.keys())(soilLayer)))` is an extremely convoluted way of doing `max(vs[0] for vs in soilLayer.values())`, or for that matter, `max(map(itemgetter(0), soilLayer.values()))`

Comment: thanks a lot, I will use this, without importing: max(vs[0] for vs in soilLayer.values())